# Magento 1.5.1 Installation Error

Tags: magento, installation

I receive the following error messages after I set the Base URL and database information. Here is the complete dump:

```
Error in file: "/var/www/docroot/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/sql/core_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.8.0-0.8.1.php" - SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1030 Got error 28 from storage engine

Trace:
#0 /var/www/docroot/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(390): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')
#1 /var/www/docroot/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(289): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('upgrade', '0.8.0', '0.8.28')
#2 /var/www/docroot/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(233): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_upgradeResourceDb('0.8.0', '0.8.28')
#3 /var/www/docroot/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(161): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates()
#4 /var/www/docroot/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(399): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
#5 /var/www/docroot/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(329): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#6 /var/www/docroot/store/app/Mage.php(627): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#7 /var/www/docroot/store/index.php(81): Mage::run('', 'store')
#8 {main}
```

I've seen several supposed fixes for similar errors on Google, but none of them have worked. Can anyone help make sense of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [Linux System Error Code table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/operating-system-error-codes.html) reveals, that error 28 corresponds to

> 28    ENOSPC  No space left on device

If you are on a shared host and you are using some global/shared MySQL instance, there is probably not much *you* can do about it.